# Как поместить два контейнера по горизонтали?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Объединил в один контейнер и прописал display:inline-block тогда таблицы съезжают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего использовать **Flexbox**. Вот минимальный пример:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .flex-container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .flex-element {
      width: 50%;
      height: 100px;
    }
    
    .red {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .green {
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-element red"></div>
    <div class="flex-element green"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```